# Show remaining values in a second DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've been told to make an enrollment system for my Institute, this is my Database:

```
`create table ingreso
(RNE int primary key not null,
Apellido nvarchar(50),
Nombre nvarchar(50),
Procedencia nvarchar(50),
Encargado nvarchar(50),
Telefono int,
Edad int,
Instituto_Anterior nvarchar(100),
Promedio int)`
```

I've used a `textbox` for each field, and two `DataGridView` for the next thing:

First of all, I enter all the info I need into the database(SQL server 2014), then I have a button named `order`, that shows in the `DataGridView` only the number of `rows` that are specified in a textbox named `txtfiltro`, in the other `DataGridView` it should show me the remaining data, but instead, shows me all the data in the `database`, this is my code:

```
int i=0;

// Makes the Query
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(" Select RNE, Nombres, Apellidos, Promedio from Ingreso order by Promedio desc;", sqlConnection);

// obtains the number required by user
int numeroRegistros = Convert.ToInt32(txtfiltro.Text);

using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   // Charges data to the object
   var dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Load(dr);

   // checks that data has been obtained
   if(dt.Rows!= null && dt.Rows.Count>0)
   {
       // Obtains what user wanted
       var pedidosPorUsuario = dt.AsEnumerable().Take(numeroRegistros);

       // Obtains remaining data
       var restantes = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r=>{
          i++;
          return i>numeroRegistros;
       });

       // Converts to DataTable and asigns to DataGridView
       this.dgvRequeridos.DataSource = pedidosPorUsuario.Count() > 0 ? pedidosPorUsuario.CopyToDataTable() : null;
       this.dgvRestantes.DataSource = restantes.Count() > 0 ? restantes .CopyToDataTable() : null;

   }
   else
   {
      this.dgvRequeridos.DataSource = null;
      this.dgvRestantes.DataSource = null;
   }

   this.dgvRequeridos.Refresh();
   this.dgvRestantes.Refresh();

}
```

What should I do to make the second `DataGridView` show me only the data that did not enter in the range specified in txtfiltro??

this is my comlete code:

```
namespace Sistema_Matrícula
    {
    public partial class Ingreso_Datos : Form
    {
        public Ingreso_Datos()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = Conexión.connection;

        private void llenargrid()
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select RNE, Apellidos, Nombres, Promedio from Ingreso", sqlConnection);


                using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var datable = new DataTable();
                    datable.Load(dr);
                    this.dgvAlumnos.DataSource = datable;
                    this.dgvAlumnos.Refresh();
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
        }

        private void btnagregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into Ingreso values (@RNE," +
                "@Apellidos," +
                "@Nombres," +
                "@Procedencia," +
                "@Encargado," +
                "@Telefono," +
                "@Edad," +
                "@Instituto_Anterior," +
                "@Promedio)", sqlConnection);

            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("RNE", txtRNE.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Apellidos", txtApellidos.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nombres", txtNombres.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Procedencia", txtProcedencia.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Encargado", txtEncargado.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Telefono", txtTelefono.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Edad", txtEdad.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Instituto_Anterior", txtColegio.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Promedio", txtPromedio.Text);

            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Guardado Exitosamente!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de Guardado...", ex.Message);
            }
            sqlConnection.Close();
            llenargrid();
        }

        private void btneliminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvAlumnos.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Desea eliminar este registro?", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    var codigoSeleccionado = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvAlumnos.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Delete from Ingreso where RNE = @RNE", sqlConnection);
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("RNE", codigoSeleccionado);


                    try
                    {
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        sqlConnection.Close();
                        llenargrid();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        MessageBox.Show("No se pudo eliminar este Campo...", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                        throw;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        private void btnordenar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SET ROWCOUNT " + txtfiltro.Text + " Select RNE, Nombres, Apellidos, Promedio from Ingreso order by Promedio desc;", sqlConnection);

                using (SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var datable = new DataTable();
                    datable.Load(dr);
                    this.dgvAlumnos.DataSource = datable;
                    this.dgvAlumnos.Refresh();
                }
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            }
        }

        private void Ingreso_Datos_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            llenargrid();
        }





        private void btnnuevo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtRNE.Text = "";
            txtApellidos.Text = "";
            txtNombres.Text = "";
            txtEncargado.Text = "";
            txtTelefono.Text = "";
            txtProcedencia.Text = "";
            txtEdad.Text = "";
            txtPromedio.Text = "";
            txtColegio.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use all the remaining rows of the datatable this might help you

```
var data = datable.AsEnumerable().ToList();
var remainingData = new List<DataRow>();
for (int i = numeroRegistros; i < data.Count; i++)
{
    remainingData.Add(data[i]);
}
```

I think it should work now

Comment: Hello there! well, it throws me an error, "Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'DataRow' and 'int' "

Comment: Hello!, sorry, but I still have an error, it shows me the first data + 1, and I only need it to show the other data that does not enter in the range specified. one question, in `take`, what should I put? numeroRegistros?, I'm sorry if I bother you, but I really need to solve this, please.

Comment: I made some changes, tell me if you solved your problem

Comment: Hey there!!! it worked, Thank you very much!! I appreciate your time, thanks, a lot!!